# Strapi: what is best way to combine multiply Collections in one endpoint?

Tags: strapi

lets imagine that we have 2 independent data collections:

1. **menu** (contains labels + links [])
2. **posts** (contains text [])

By default Strapi gives me 2 endpoints, one for menu and another for posts. That's fine, but how I can combine this two (or even 10+ small data collections) in **one** Strapi REST API response?

I'm new to Strapi so need most simple and effective solution. I know that possible to make a custom endpoint but in this case I should manually add/remove any collections inside Strapi config  - think its not a true way.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can also create another collection e.g. `agg_collection` that has relations to both collections so you can retrieve them by calling `api/agg_collection?populate=...`.

Writing a custom endpoint is the preferred solution I suppose, but the question is; do you really need to have it in a single request?